# Class & Object not being recognized

Tags: java

I'm creating a loan application program for a portfolio. However, I seemed to forgot how to call/invoke/create a method from another class. I'm sure I'm not making sense! Here's the snippet of my code:

```
  public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    String firstName = LoanerFirstName.getText();
    String middleI = LoanerMiddleInitial.getText();
    String lastName = LoanerLastName.getText();
    double interest = Double.parseDouble(AIR.getText());
    int Years = Integer.parseInt(NumOfYears.getText());
    double loanAmount = Double.parseDouble(LoanAmount.getText());
    double monthlyPayment = Double.parseDouble(MonthlyPayment.getText());
    double totalPayment = Double.parseDouble(TotalPayment.getText()); 

    Loan loan = new Loan(interest, Years, loanAmount);
 MonthlyPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f", loan.getMonthlyPayment()));
 TotalPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f", loan.getTotalPayment()));
    }
```

The "Loan" Class isn't being recognized (underlined in red; error).

P.S: I'm using NetBeans 8.0 for Windows 8.

Comment: Check the imports in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your classes before using it.

if you use:

```
Loan loan = new Loan(interest, Years, loanAmount);
```

Verify if you have your `import` for that class.

If you are using a class inside a lib, verify you have the jar file in your classpath, then you need to have the import for the class you need.

Comment: I'm going to try it later. Thank you for your input...!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dear Friend,

You first have to import the class you want to use if it is in different package as concerned to your present class as :

import packagename.Loan;
where packagename is the name of package containing Loan class

If the class Loan is in the same package then, you can access it directly as:

Create its object and call its constructor at the same time as ---- 
  Loan loan = new Loan(interest, Years, loanAmount);

And now using its object loan , you can access different data members of that class.
Hope this would effectively help you.
Thanks.
```